# CSS sub-menu selection

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Selecting parent menu shoud show child menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391499/selecting-parent-menu-shoud-show-child-menu)

[image]

The image shows Parent Menu that is Tutorial and it's Sub Menu as Photo Shop,Illustrator,Flash,Html,Php and so on.When i Hover on Tutorial the sub menu appears. 
The problem i am facing is that when i click on child menu Photoshop it goes to next page that is Photoshop but there Tutorial remains un selected and sub menu disappear.

How to keep it selected in it's Child Page as well.

Comment: I didn't understand a word. Please rephrase to explain better.

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? And if you asked the same question yesterday what was wrong with the answer provided to you?

Comment: -1 Unreadable question. You need to start over, making things clearer. Adding some example code would help too.

Comment: Why did you [accept the answer on your first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391499/selecting-parent-menu-shoud-show-child-menu) if you were just going to post it a second time?

Comment: My question is that i am making a menu in my site.Tutorial is main menu and photo shop is sub menu.When i click on Photo-shop then go in photo-shop page.When I am at photo-shop page then Sub-menu with parent menu should also be visible.

Comment: @Sparky672 My project-manager changed the requirements of the menu selection.

Comment: yesterday i showed the solution but today i got the new change in the menu selection

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it my self .Thanks for Nice responses @Christian Varga @Sparky672